# Add a download button on jplayer playing track

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer, audio-player

I am successfully initializing jplayer in:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function() {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            title: options.title || '',
            mp3: options.mp3[scope.activeTrack] || null,
        });
    }
});
```

I know I can get the data with:

```
jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_1").data('jPlayer')
```

What I don't know is how can I get the current streaming url in order to create a download button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(yourSelector).data().jPlayer.status.src
```

It's all on the website: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-object